# PyMol: Adding dashed lines to structure via Python

Tags: python, pymol

I am using Pymol to load a pdb file for molecular representation. Using the PyMol python library I am creating cylinder as a `cgo` (compiled graphics) object.

Example code is as follows:

```
import pymol
from pymol.cgo import *
import sys

pymol.pymol_argv = ['pymol', ''] + sys.argv[1:]
pymol.finish_launching()

pymol.cmd.load('1V6R.pdb')   # This is a pdb protein file.

cyl = [CYLINDER,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,radius,r1,g1,b1,r2,g2,b2]

pymol.cmd.load_cgo(cyl, 'cylinder')

pymol.cmd.hide(representation='everything', selection=str(pymol.cmd.get_names()[0])

pymol.cmd.show(representation='ribbon', selection=str(pymol.cmd.get_names()[0]))

pymol.cmd.orient()
```

After running this python script, PyMol opens with this representation:

[image]

In the above image, the protein ribbon (green) is loaded from the pdb file, and the cylinder(white) is the `cgo` cylinder object.

What I want is to be able to script adding **dashed lines** to the representation, But there doesn't seem to be a `cgo` for dashed lines. In the worst case scenario, I could see having to script a bunch of cylinders on the same 'ray' and call that a dashed line, but I would obviously prefer an easier method.

Is there a way of using PyMol python scripting to represent dashed lines?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to use the [distance](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Distance) command